# 19.10 How to show mounted volumes on the desktop?

Tags: gnome, 19.10, desktop-icons

The only option that I'm seeing in Gnome Tweaks is to turn the visibility of the Home folder and Trash icon on and off, which doesn't work for me. I can show mounted volumes in my Dash to Dock but I don't want that. I want them to show on my desktop. Is that actually possible to have happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 19.10, which now uses a Gnome shell extension to provide icons on the desktop, it is not (yet?) possible to display mounted volumes on the desktop.

If a workflow with mounted volumes on the desktop is critical to you, you may need to consider moving to a desktop environment that still supports that (KDE desktop on Kubuntu, XFCE on Xubuntu, Cinnamon desktop...).

Alternatively, it is technically possible to replace nautilus file manager by another file manager that can provide icons of the desktop, but then you venture on your own.

Comment: Thank you vanadium, I really appreciate your input. I thought MAYBE I was overlooking something so I decided to ask.

Comment: You are welcome.  At least, the possibility to have mounted volumes on the dock is back in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes it is :) That's a start, it just really doesn't help me at all in my workflow LOL